# How to persist `event_scheduler` to be `ON` even if MySQL is restarted?

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduler, mysql-event

I want to persist `event_scheduler` to be `ON` even if MySQL is restarted; how can I achieve this?

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: one way - you can set system variables, and use those variables whenever needed (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One Way - You can set your system variables and use those variables if there is any possibility to restart your mysql.

Here is link [Using system variables in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html)

Comment: "If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and used for new connections until the server restarts. (To make a global system variable setting permanent, you should set it in an option file)"

Answer (score 49):

You can set

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

in `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file, then restart your server for the setting to take effect.

Once set `event_scheduler` will always remain `ON` no matter whether your server restarts.

Comment: On my case (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS), adding it to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` did the trick, while adding it to `/etc/mysql/my.ini` did nothing.

Comment: On a Windows machine with MySQL 5.7, `event-scheduler=on` worked for me

Comment: Make sure you add the setting into the proper section - it should go under `[mysqld]`. Otherwise the server won't be able to start...

Comment: And of course you have to put it into the right file. I had two files, one `D:\MariaDB\my.ini` and one `D:\MariaDB\data\my.ini` . Not sure why but during the installation the latter one was the one which is used.

Comment: on an Amazon Linux AMI image, it worked by modifying the /etc/my.cfg file. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Open your **/etc/mysql/my.ini** file and add:

```
event_scheduler = on
```

under the **[mysqld]** section

*(tested under mysql 5.5.35-0+wheezy1 - Debian)*

Comment: In some linux distros, the file is under /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Was necessary for me, using MariaDB, include the line inside the [mysqld] section as suggested.

Comment: /usr/local/etc/mysql for FreeBSD

Comment: Using MariaDB from RHSCL, the config file would be in **/etc/opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/my.cnf** (change 103 to your version)

Comment: For MariaDB be aware the [mysqld] is required and doesn't work with [mysql], only [mysqld]. Tested in Raspbian

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Add this line at the end of the file:

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

Than reboot and check if daemon is started after reboot:

Log into mysql bash:

```
mysql -u <user> -p
```

Than run the command:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Now you should see the event scheduler daemon in the list

Comment: this worked at ubuntu 16.04 i wasnt able to edit the my.cnf file.

Answer (score 3):

On our Windows Server 2012 system, none of these or any other solutions worked. Then I looked at the registry entry for start up:

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56`

The trick, the evil, is `ProgramData`. It's not `Program Files`. Look in Program Files and you'll see a `my-default.ini` file, put there just to royally screw you up.

The trick is to find the path in the registry, which was for me: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Services\MySQL56`

Answer (score 1):

[event_scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) (global variable) is `ON` by default so if you restart MySQL, `event_scheduler` is reset to `ON`.

But, if you want `event_scheduler` to be `OFF`(`0`) even if MySQL is restarted, you can persist `event_scheduler` to be `OFF`(`0`) with the SQL below. *The change of `event_scheduler` is immediately applied just after running the SQL below and `ON`(`1`) is available for `event_scheduler` and `event_scheduler` session variable doesn't exists and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html) explains how to persist global variables:

```sql
SET PERSIST event_scheduler = OFF;
```

Or:

```sql
SET PERSIST event_scheduler = 0;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@PERSIST.event_scheduler = OFF;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@PERSIST.event_scheduler = 0;
```

In addition, you can disable `event_scheduler` to persist with the SQL below. *The SQL below doesn't change `event_scheduler` global variable and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset-persist.html) explains how to disable persisted global variables:

```sql
RESET PERSIST event_scheduler;
```

And, you can show `event_scheduler` persisted variable with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-persisted-variables-table.html) explains `persisted_variables` table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.persisted_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler';
```