# MySQL Event Scheduler - Grant SUPER Privileges not working

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to set:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

or

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

I get:

**#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation**

So, I try this:

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.*
TO 'username'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and I get:

**#1045 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

How can I grant the SUPER priviledges?

Related questions:

[How to set global event_scheduler=ON even if MySQL is restarted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112395/how-to-set-global-event-scheduler-on-even-if-mysql-restart)

[how to add super privileges to mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database)

Comment: does the account you're logged into mysql with have `grant` privileges?

Comment: I clicked ALL PRIVILEGES and these are the ones that show up:
ALTER,
 CREATE,
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,
 DELETE,
 EVENT,
 INDEX,
 LOCK TABLES,
 SELECT,
 TRIGGER,
 ALTER ROUTINE,
 CREATE ROUTINE,
 CREATE VIEW,
 DROP,
 EXECUTE,
 INSERT,
 REFERENCES,
 SHOW VIEW,
 UPDATE,

Comment: irrelevant. the account you're logged into must have the `WITH GRANT` option. That's a META-privilege - the ability to assign privileges to others.

Answer (score 0):

First, to change the value of the [global event_scheduler system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-privileges.html) you need [SUPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privileges... and that and only that account with that privileges can change it... it's impossible if you don't have that privilege.

Try `GRANT EVENT ON [myschema].* TO [username]@[localhost];`

Comment: I get: #1044 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'myschema'

Comment: In `myschema` use the schema your using (replace it)... if still gets the error means you can't do that because of privileges

Comment: Yeah, it gives me the same result. I'm using economy hosting from goDaddy so it may not be available.

Comment: Ok so that's it, GoDaddy doesn't let you have the `SUPER` privilege to administer because in that case you would get the whole server.

Comment: What do you suggest as a work around? Can I change the MySQL configuration file?

Comment: I'm not sure about your reason of changing global variables... but in this case (and many other third-party services) you **can't** change the configuration because it counts as a vulnerability

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to run a SQL script at certain times of the day. I may consider looking into cron jobs.

Comment: Yeah, it's the only way