# sql event isn't executing automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have created an event in HeideSQL. i just wanna change a value in a table if the value is 2 to 0 after 3 minutes of data insertion. I can execute the query. But i wanna make it automatic. so I created an event. but it is not working automatically. Could someone please help.

Settings as follows:

Name: changeValueEvent
Definer: root@localhost
Drop event after expiration : checked ( tried unchecked  as well)
state: enable

Timing:

every: 2 Minutes
starts at : 04/01/2019    2:00:00 PM

executing body:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE data SET data.VALUE = 0
        WHERE data.TIME <= date_sub(NOW(), interval 3 MINUTE)
          and data.VALUE = 2;

END
```

```
    //data is the name if table
    //wanna update VALUE column. 
    //TIME column carries the time of data 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE data SET data.VALUE = 0
            WHERE data.TIME <= date_sub(NOW(), interval 3 MINUTE)
              and data.VALUE = 2;

    END
```

Comment: Why you are not creating sql job and execute that job in regular interval?

Comment: but why isn't working. but i can execute manually and it works!

Comment: Check if event scheduler is turned on. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%event_scheduler%'`. If it says `OFF`, then your scheduler isn't running. @KevinShah - what is *"sql job"* that you mentioned?

Comment: @Mjh

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `changeValueEvent`
 ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 2 MINUTE STARTS '2019-04-01 02:00:00'
 ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
 ENABLE
 COMMENT 'somecomment'
 DO BEGIN

UPDATE data SET data.VALUE = 0 WHERE data.TIME <= date_sub(NOW(), interval 3 MINUTE) and data.VALUE = 2;
END

Comment: @Mjh sql provides option to create a job that we can execute in regular interval. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @KevinShah why are you linking documentation for Microsoft SQL Server? This question is about MySQL. In MySQL we have an Event Scheduler that runs events on predefined intervals. I have no idea how you plan to use *"sql job"* that's meant for Microsoft SQL server, but I am interested to read about it. Can you please explain?

Comment: @KevinShah any chance for an answer to my question?

Comment: @Mjh Yes one  thing that I miss that MySql tag. :(

Comment: still, I haven't got any answer for my question :(

Comment: @dayDreamer I asked you whether your event scheduler is turned on and I gave you the query that checks it. You didn't read what I wrote and replied with the same query you used in question. What exactly did you expect? Could you please **read** first?

Comment: @Mjh sorry!. I just checked it. it says OFF.  Dunno how to to turn it ON. Tried to change value to ON. it gives warning : Access denied for user 'root@localhost to databse 'information_schema' !! any help?

Comment: Here's how, [follow the white rabbit :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23487522/1133682)

Comment: Do `SET event_scheduler = ON;`, then run  `SELECT @@event_scheduler;`  Meanwhile, add it to `my.cnf` so it will be turned on upon the next restart.